# Base64ToCamera throws error: The image could not be decoded when trying to save the image in gallery in Ionic 3 project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm working on Ionic 3 Project that has camera preview. When I take a picture (I made an alert that will show the error and the string) and try to save the image in the gallery but I'm getting this error: The image could not be decoded.

[Error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWR0g.png)

What could possibly be wrong here?

Here's my function: (I'm using camera preview and base64toGallery plugins)

```js
takePicture(){

    // picture options
    const pictureOpts: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = {
      width: 1280,
      height: 1280,
      quality: 85
    }

    // take a picture
    this.cameraPreview.takePicture(pictureOpts).then((imageData) => {
      this.picture = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.base64ToGallery.base64ToGallery(this.picture).then(
        res => this.showAlert('Saved image to gallery '),
        err => this.showAlert(err+ '  '+ this.picture)
      );
      //this.showAlert(this.picture)
      
    
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.picture = 'assets/img/test.jpg';
    });


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
this.base64ToGallery.base64ToGallery(this.picture).then(
```

to this:

```
this.base64ToGallery.base64ToGallery(imageData).then(
```